# How to get static reference data without creating entity?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring mvc app, in which I need to show country list in a HTML dropdown. I have a country table in db in which there are 2 fields, countryid and countryname. How can I get country id and name without creating country model, using Hibernate? I have tried the following code:

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("select countryid, countryname from country");
List list = query.list();
```

The problem is that list contains objects and I don't know how to extract countryid and countryname from object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`query.list()` returns a list of object arrays, and each element in the list represents one row returned from SQL query.

So, in your case, you can do this

```
List<Object[]> list = (List<Object>)query.list();
for (Object[] country : list) {
    System.out.println("Country id: " + country[0] + ", country name: " + country[1]);
}
```

Comment: You're welcome, glad I helped. P.S. Consider marking your answered question as answered, it would help others in search for solutions to similar problems.

Comment: You need to accept the correct answer. I'm not talking just about this particular question, I see you have asked 27 questions and you don't have a single accepted answer. Please [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for instructions.

Comment: I am using following code to show on jsp page, but it is not sorted. How can I sort this?


<c:forEach items="${statemap}" var="state">  
          <option value='<c:out value="${state.key}"></c:out>'><c:out value="${state.value}"></c:out></option>  
       </c:forEach>

Comment: You need to sort it in the query. Add something like `order by countryname asc` at the end of the query.

Comment: You are using `Map` to store countries, which isn't sorted. Check out [this article](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-sort-a-map-in-java/) on how to sort maps by keys or values, whatever you need.